# jQuery sortables in a (graphical) tree structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am having problems trying to use the jQuery-ui sortable interaction in a graphical tree like structure.

I want to be able to drag the child items from one position in the tree to another position in the tree. Right now I can only move them across the same level.

This is my tree structure:

```
<div class="parent item">
  <div class="data"><span>Parent Item</span></div>
  <div class="children">
    <div class="item" style="width: 50%;">
      <div class="data"><span>Child Item</span></div>
      <div class="children">
        <div class="item" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="data"><span>Child Item</span></div>
          <div class="children">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="data"><span>Child Item</span></div>
          <div class="children">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 50%;">
      <div class="data"><span>Child Item</span></div>
      <div class="children">
        <div class="item" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="data"><span>Child Item</span></div>
          <div class="children">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="data"><span>Child Item</span></div>
          <div class="children">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(a screenshot of what it produces)
[image: a screenshot of what it produces]

And here is the jQuery-ui sortable function

```
$(".children").sortable({
   items: ".item",
   containment: ".parent",
   connectWith: ".children"
});
```

I have recreated this in CodePen http://codepen.io/viralpickaxe/pen/wfqxc

Comment: I'm unable to move anything anywhere in the shared pen, i don't see a `.children-container` in there. Can you explain what's the relationship between `.item`, `.data`, `.children` etc..? because i'm getting confusing seeing the `.item` classes on both `.parent` as well as inside and outside the `.children`

Comment: 1. Your option "connectWith" reffered to selector ".children-container", but you do not have such class at your HTML dom

2. What should happen whan you move one part of the tree to other place? it will become not a binary tree (you need some kind of "tree balancing" after movement?)

Comment: @NikitaHolovach sorry I copied the javascript from my actual project and forgot to change this line when I rewrote the tree to make it clearer

Comment: @TilwinJoy Are you sure nothing is dragging? The structure is basically everything is inside the parent, and in the parent it has a .children div. Inside of that there are items with again have .children div's. The .data is just a container for stuff like the name and such

Comment: It's dragging but not dropping… So nothing can be sorted. Dragging isn't the functionality of sortable. So what's `.item`..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy you can actual "move" the right side into the left side but nothing else. Any ideas why this interaction works but nothing else

Comment: @TilwinJoy Item is a "thing" that needs to be moved around

Comment: @viralpickaxe Why i asked all this is because from that demo, i don't think you've made any honest attempt to solve the issue (*otherwise you'd have at least named the children `child1`, `child2` etc to check whether it's working*), it just looks like some thrown away code asking others to fix it.

Comment: @so If so, the `.parent` also has `.item` class. Where will you move that *thing*  to..? Your code and description really doesn't look like you've made an attempt to solve the issue (or for some reason it doesn't match)

Comment: @TilwinJoy Its really not, I rewrote the html because the actual code from the project Im working on is too complicated to post in here (lots of attributes and stuff)

Comment: @viralpickaxe so, since `.item` are things needs to ne moved around, why does `.parent` has `.item` class..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not  fully resolve your issue but sortable start working right way...

You should add to class children  min-height or  overflow, because it height  0 you cant place elements there

```
.children{
    min-height:20px;
}
```

Additionally I'd like to recommend you use placeholder:

```
.placeholder{
    background:red;
}
```

and js:

```
$(".children").sortable({
   items: ".item",
   containment: ".parent",
   connectWith: ".children",
   placeholder:'placeholder'
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, (not fully working as you said) but just a couple of tweaks now that I have to make :)

Answer (score 1):

This in not a complete answer, but you could find a workaround using `draggable` and `droppable` instead of `sortable`:

```
$(".item").draggable( { appendTo: "body",
                        helper: "clone"})
          .droppable( {  drop: function( event, ui ) {
                               ui.draggable.appendTo( this );
           } });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/stDik

There are still a few things to do (set a size to empty children so that they can receive new ones, update the target position when the user is dragging an item, etc.) but the basic feature seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you, a good answer as well and works ok. But I prefer to use something less "hacky".